# How to get stats of search operations groups in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch 1.1.1, I'm trying to get stats gathered by search operations groups.

In [documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/indices-stats.html), it's said you can set a custom group at search time for your search operation, and you can then get stats from these groups using the [stats API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/indices-stats.html).

Here what I'm doing on an existing myIndex index:

```
> curl -XGET http://host:9200/myIndex/myType/_search -d '{
    "size":1,"query":{"match_all":{}},"stats":["group1","group2"]}'
{
   "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5,
        "total": 5
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {[...]}
        ],
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "total": 52
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 1
}
```

After some time I'm getting stats:

```
> curl -XGET http://host:9200/myIndex/_stats/search?groups=group1,group2
{
    "_all": {
        "primaries": {
            "search": {
                "fetch_current": 0,
                "fetch_time_in_millis": 5676,
                "fetch_total": 2468,
                "open_contexts": 0,
                "query_current": 0,
                "query_time_in_millis": 31166,
                "query_total": 4530
            }
        },
        "total": {
            "search": {
                "fetch_current": 0,
                "fetch_time_in_millis": 5676,
                "fetch_total": 2468,
                "open_contexts": 0,
                "query_current": 0,
                "query_time_in_millis": 31166,
                "query_total": 4530
            }
        }
    },
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 5,
        "total": 10
    },
    "indices": {
        "myIndex": {
            "primaries": {
                "search": {
                    "fetch_current": 0,
                    "fetch_time_in_millis": 5676,
                    "fetch_total": 2468,
                    "open_contexts": 0,
                    "query_current": 0,
                    "query_time_in_millis": 31166,
                    "query_total": 4530
                }
            },
            "total": {
                "search": {
                    "fetch_current": 0,
                    "fetch_time_in_millis": 5676,
                    "fetch_total": 2468,
                    "open_contexts": 0,
                    "query_current": 0,
                    "query_time_in_millis": 31166,
                    "query_total": 4530
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I see nowhere any trace of my groups in the stats payload. I get the exact same result without my groups in the requert: `curl -XGET http://host:9200/myIndex/_stats/search`

Do you know how to retrieve the stats of group1 and group2?

My elasticsearch version:

```
{
    status: 200,
    name: "myclustername",
    version: {
    number: "1.1.1",
    build_hash: "f1585f096d3f3985e73456debdc1a0745f512bbc",
    build_timestamp: "2014-04-16T14:27:12Z",
    build_snapshot: false,
    lucene_version: "4.7"
    },
    tagline: "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  is a bug in [1.1.1](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/6390) which was fixed in[1.3.0](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-3-0) .

Comment: weird works for me in 1.4.2 with POST  i'll try on 1.1.1 later and get back

Comment: i can confirm it doesn't work on 1.1.1 a bug that was fixed in 1.3.0

Comment: It makes more sense now... Thanks for the link to the pull request!